# test works with "$f" but not with "$@"

Tags: command-line-arguments, sh

I was writing a little bash script and noticed an odd thing. Basically it's just when I execute this:

```
if [ "$@" = "spam with eggs" ]
then
    echo "yay"
else
    echo "nay"
fi
```

This gives the following error:

```
$ sh spam.sh spam with eggs
spam.sh: 3: [: =: unexpected operator
nay
```

But if I change the script to the following, it works:

```
f="$@"
if [ "$f" = "spam with eggs" ]
then
    echo "yay"
else
    echo "nay"
fi
```

Why doesn't it work with `"$@"` in the first place?

Comment: I would suggest that if the order of `spam`, `with`, and `eggs` is important, then the command should be invoked as `sh spam.sh "spam with eggs"`, and then you would simply use `$1` instead of either `$@` or `$*`. The question is, does `spam.sh` *conceptually* take one argument or multiple arguments?

Comment: Coneptually it doesn't matter. The script I was writing while I had this problem was just some playing around while I was bored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `"$@"` is very specifically rigged to preserve whitespace exactly as it was.  In your example, it returns three strings, not one.  You want `"$*"` here. (That's unusual; most people have the opposite problem.)